# Ordered merge of two timeseries (each with unique DateTimeIndex) and ffilling?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
time                       price
2015-11-18 00:00:00.000    42.02
2015-11-18 00:00:00.021    42.01
2015-11-18 00:00:00.126    42.01
2015-11-18 00:00:00.127    42.02
Name: price, dtype: float64

time                       price
2015-11-18 00:00:00.000    106.82
2015-11-18 00:00:00.020    106.82
2015-11-18 00:00:00.021    106.82
2015-11-18 00:00:00.207    106.82
2015-11-18 00:00:00.325    106.82
Name: price, dtype: float64
```

I would like to merge these two unique DataFrames (let's say one is stock1, one is stock2) into a multi-index (by stock1 and stock2) DataFrame as follows:

```
                            STOCK1          STOCK2
time                       price
2015-11-18 00:00:00.000    106.82           42.02
2015-11-18 00:00:00.126    106.82           42.01
2015-11-18 00:00:00.127    106.82           42.02
2015-11-18 00:00:00.020    106.82           42.02
2015-11-18 00:00:00.021    106.82           42.01
2015-11-18 00:00:00.021    106.82           42.01   
2015-11-18 00:00:00.207    106.82           42.01   
2015-11-18 00:00:00.325    106.82           42.01
```

When I try making a multi-index first, I get

> ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

Tried ordered_merge as well but it is not getting the right result.

Does it make sense to first reindex Stock1 and Stock2 by their union then multi-indexing them? What is the best process to achieve the result?

Answer (score 0):

I lost the date info when I read it it, but this should work

```
In [37]: df = pd.concat([s1, s2], keys=['stock1', 'stock2'], axis=1).fillna(method='ffill')

In [38]: df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(['price', df.columns])

In [39]: df
Out[39]:
              price
             stock1  stock2
00:00:00.000  42.02  106.82
00:00:00.020  42.02  106.82
00:00:00.021  42.01  106.82
00:00:00.126  42.01  106.82
00:00:00.127  42.02  106.82
00:00:00.207  42.02  106.82
00:00:00.325  42.02  106.82
```

`concat` basically does an outer join / union of the index labels here.
I have the column levels flipped from how you had your input since they share the outermost level. If you really want it as in your example flip the last one to `pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.columns, 'price'])`